# remove blanks from combobox with two lists

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to remove the blank records from a combobox with two lists.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim N As Range
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

PREST.ColumnCount = 2
Set ws = Worksheets("L_Location")
LastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim i, j As Integer

Dim location(2 To 100, 1 To 2) As String


For j = 1 To 2
For i = 2 To LastRow
If ws.Cells(i, j).Value <> vbNullString Then
location(i, j) = ws.Cells(i, j).Value
End If
Next i
Next j
PREST.List = location
End Sub
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What if you change to: If ws.Cells(i, j).Value <> vbNullString and ws.Cells(i, j).Value <> "" Then

Comment: You want to remove if both cells on the same row are blanks, or any of them? What you are doing currently is "any", but you might loose the correct associations that are on the same row.

Comment: still have blanks, the table im using has just one row populated for testing, the data from that row shows but i get a lot of blanks with it, i didnt have that problem with one column comboboxes

Comment: Im assuming that the two cells on the row have data, because i did set a condition when entering them so u cannot have one blank, either the two are blank or the two have data

Answer (score 1):

You are having blanks because your 2D array is already sized with 100 rows. A simple workaround would be to first count the non-empty rows, then dimension the Array accordingly.

```
Dim location() As String
Dim count As Long
count = Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Cells.count

ReDim location(1 To count, 1 To 2)

'then continue from here to fill the array
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will fill the combobox with your range value then will delete any empty item:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    PREST.ColumnCount = 2
    Set ws = Worksheets("L_Location")
    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Long ', j As Integer


    PREST.List = ws.Range("a1:b" & LastRow).Value
    For i = PREST.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
     If PREST.List(i) = "" Then PREST.RemoveItem i
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this :

```
Dim location() As String
ReDim location(LastRow - 2, 1)

For j = 0 To 1
For i = 0 To LastRow - 2
  If ws.Cells(i + 2, j + 1).Value <> vbNullString And ws.Cells(i + 2, j +  1).Value <> "" Then
    location(i, j) = ws.Cells(i + 2, j + 1).Value
  End If
Next i
Next j
PREST.List = location
```

which seems to work but i guess its gonna give me an error if the list is empty (lastrow = 1)

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that any two cells on the same row are both either blank or with values, then you could go like follows:

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Long, j As Long

PREST.ColumnCount = 2
With Worksheets("L_Location") '<--| reference your worksheet
    With .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<--| reference its column A not empty cells from row 1 down to last not empty one
        Dim location(1 To .Count, 1 To 2) As String '<--| size your array rows number to that of referenced cells
        For Each cell In .Cells '<--| loop through referenced cells
            i = i + 1 '<--| update array row index
            For j = 1 To 2 '<--| loop through array columns
                location(i, j) = cell.Offset(j -1).Value '<--| fill array
            Next j
        Next cell
    End With
End With


PREST.List = location
```